# Is there a mark-up language to describe meanings?

Tags: text, markup, semantic-markup

I am curious if there is actually a mark-up language to describe the meanings of a text:

Here some example of what I mean and how it could look like:

```
<text>Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A site that’s free. Free to ask questions,
free to answer questions, free to read, free to index, built with plain old HTML, no
fake rot13 text on the home page, no scammy google-cloaking tactics, no salespeople, no
JavaScript windows dropping down in front of the answer asking for $12.95 to go away.
You can register if you want to collect karma and win valuable flair that will appear
next to your name, but otherwise, it’s just free. And fast. Very, very fast.</text>
```

And now I want to add meta-information to it so that i can give the text a meaning:

```
<mark from="0" to="14" object="Stack Overflow">Stack Overflow is a online community for coders.
The website is: www.stackoverflow.com</mark>
<mark from="20" to="31" object="programming" source="en.wikipedia.org/wiki/programming">
Computer programming (often shortened to programming or coding) is the process of
designing, writing, testing, debugging, and maintaining the source code of computer
programs</mark>
```

I hope there is already some language out there which I didn't find because of my bad "search"-abilities.

EDIT: I dont mean languages that are actually like HTML.

This is for me a standard html markup:

```
<p>My really <span class="important">interessting</span> paragraph</p>
```

I want to enable intersections and describe one part multiple times and not touch the original text like in my example above:

```
<text>Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A site that’s free. Free to ask questions,
free to answer questions, free to read, free to index, built with plain old HTML, no
fake rot13 text on the home page, no scammy google-cloaking tactics, no salespeople, no
JavaScript windows dropping down in front of the answer asking for $12.95 to go away.
You can register if you want to collect karma and win valuable flair that will appear
next to your name, but otherwise, it’s just free. And fast. Very, very fast.</text>
```

Now I want to markup "Stack Overflow" at the first line and describe it. Next I want to describe "programming" and tell what this is and next "Q & A" and after that comes a tricky part: I want to describe what a "programming Q & A site" is.

Here something i just make up:

```
<mark type="description" line="1" from="0" to="15" subject="Stack Overflow" language="English" source="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow">
In software, a stack overflow occurs when too much memory is used on the call stack. 
</mark>
<mark type="description" line="1" from="25" to="40" subject="programming" language="English" source="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/programming">
Computer programming (often shortened to programming or coding) is the process of designing, writing, testing, debugging, and maintaining the source code of computer programs.
</mark>
<mark type="alias" line="1" from="42" to="47" subject="Q & A" language="English">
Question and Answer
</mark>
<mark type="description" line="1" from="25" to="52" subject="programming Q & A site" language="English" author="xMRW">
A website that offers people answers on questions related to the subject programming.
</mark>
<mark type="description" line="1" from="25" to="52" subject="programming Q & A site" language="German" author="xMRW">
Das gleiche in Deutsch.
</mark>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called semantic markup. For an example you can read about [RDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework).

Start reading this article on Wipikepia about [Semantic Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web) and this introduction about [Semantic Markup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_markup), they are a good startpoint with many other links and references.

You may also be interested in:

- [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki), it's not really semantic markup but it matches more what you write in your example.
- [HTML 5 microdata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_%28HTML%29): to *simply* embed semantic metadata in your HTML markup.

Comment: this rdf-language seems very very complicated. I hope there is something simpler like my example above.^^

Comment: It depends the context. For your example you may use a Wiki (if there should be some kind of interaction with the user) or if you just need to store metadata you may think about HTML 5 microdata.

Comment: Well I think using a wiki is too much. It should be more like lets say there is some old book from "Schiller". Now I mark up some sentences to describe what he meant and to what it refers. Instead of using "pure" links I want to add meta-data to describe parts better. The original text should not be changed. It would be also a nice thing to mark up parts and translate them part by part. This rdf and Notation3 looks to me like a wikipedia-extension.

Comment: You may really consider microdata. It's a simple and quick method to add metadata to existing HTML markup.

Comment: to Wiki & Html 5 microdata: It is not quite what I mean. To use wiki and Microdata you actually have to modify the "original" text by marking it up, its too much like html. But you get big problems if you have "intersections" in the mark up. Lets say someone marks up a text from 0 to 30 and describes it. Someone else marks up 20 to 40 and describes it. This cant be accomplished easily with "xml" and "html" like languages.

Comment: Of course **you can** do it in HTML/XML! That's the purpose of RDF (a minimalist implementation is not so complex). You can extend a HTML documents with your custom tags but what you'll get is an unverifiable HTML document (and it's not a good idea). In my opinion the disadvantage of XML is that is too prolix. Moreover do not forget that a simple character index isn't a strong association with your annotations (a change on the top of your document and you will have to update ALL your indices). Take a look at http://www.1729.com/blog/HtmlAnnotations.html

Comment: "Moreover do not forget that a simple character index isn't a strong association with your annotations" (a change on the top of your document and you will have to update ALL your indices). True. I guess I have at least to make some "<p>" so it is possible to reload some parts without destroying the whole thing. Well I'll have a look at your sugestions.

Comment: I'm thinking there's not a perfect solution, overlapping annotations are problematic with XML and indices are problematic for hand written texts...

Comment: Yeah the only way for "hand written texts" would be marking up  by pixels.

Comment: We could of course digg out the guy that wrote these text, plugin a usb and get the information that way. (wait, Im back in the future)

Comment: I will give you the +rep for the question even if I'm  not very satisfied^^